# Find $H´$ at $[a,b]$ from $H(y)=\int_{-b}^{-x} f$, $x \in[-b,-a]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be continuous at $[a,b]$ and let $H(x)=\int_{-b}^{x} f$, $x \in[-b,-a]$

Find $H´$ at $[a,b]$

Comment: Is this function said to be even by any chance?

Comment: Otherwise you really don't even know that $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[-b,-a]$...

Comment: @8pir it's continuous on **$[a,b]$** but you're integrating over **$[-b,-a]$**. Sorry I misspoke in last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see edit of proof:

Let $x = -y$, then if $x \in [-b,-a] \Rightarrow y \in [a,b]$. Thus we have:

$H(x) = H(-y) = \displaystyle \int_{-b}^{-y} f(t)dt$. So the chain rule says:

$H'(x) = H'(y)\cdot \dfrac{dy}{dx} = H'(-y)\cdot \dfrac{d(-y)}{dy}\cdot \dfrac{d(-x)}{dx} = f(-y)\cdot (-1)\cdot (-1) = f(x)$

Comment: He says that $H : [-b,-a] \to \mathbb{R}$, so how does this give $H'$ on $[a,b]$?

Comment: ok, I did, the last line seems a bit convoluted to me (where do you get the $d(-x)/dx$ from?), nonetheless you state that $x \in [-b,-a]$ so again you showed $H'(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in [-b,-a]$

Comment: Really I don't think the OP's current statement can be proven. We have no idea how $H$ is defined on $[a,b]$ so we can't really find $H'$ on $[a,b]$. For instance I can define $f(x) = x$ on $[a,b]$ and then $f(x) = \cos x$ on $[-b,-a]$. We know that $H(x) = \sin x$ on $[-b,-a]$ but don't know if $H(x) = x^2/2$ on $[a,b]$